# Значення слова "глий"?

Tags: значення-слів

Цікавить значення слова "глий", яке я зустрів у вірші І. Франка "Часто я відтак до Штенгля":

> І сльота була. На шляху
>
> Геть розмок, розкисся **глий**…

Пошуки в Інтернеті не дали нічого.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Глій* може означати [«глід»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B4), зокрема про це кажуть:

- [«Словник українських наукових і народних назв судинних рослин» (Ю. Кобів, 2004)](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B3%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%B9&dicts=14&highlight=on);
- [«Етимологічний словник української мови» в 7 томах](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom1.pdf#page526).

Але наврядчи Франко мав на увазі, що розкисся якийсь кущ.

Імовірніше — розкислася **глина** на дорозі. Зокрема той самий «Етимологічний словник української мови» в 7 томах [на сторінці 524](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom1.pdf#page524) дає похідне від *глина* діалектне слово *глинь* (щоправда в значенні «алюміній»). А ще багато словників (зокрема, [«Словник української мови» в 20 томах](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=18688&page=639) і [словники на R2U](//r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9&highlight=on)) подають слово *глей* (іноді *ґлей*) у значенні «глина», «мул», «глина з мулом» — причому той самий «Етимологічний словник української мови» в 7 томах [на сторінці 521](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom1.pdf#page521) подає *глий* як один із діалектних варіантів слова *глей*.